# How data is mapped in output file after MR job in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, syncsort-dmx-h

I have an input file with one of the column as ID and another column as counter value. Based on the counter value, I am filtering data from input to output file. I made a task in DMExpress and checked for the counter and ID. I have 10 rows for each id in the input file. If counter value for each id is 3 then I will extract top 3 rows for this ID and then check for the next ID. While running this task in hadoop, Hadoop is taking the first 3 record of several IDs and creating the new file(when desired size reached) for other IDs.

Now, when hadoop is writing the record in file 0, it is extracting 3 records for ID X, but when it is writing the another part of the output file (file 1), it is writing the first record from the ID X of the previous file(which was at the last line of the file 0 . It is 4th record for the ID X). This in return increasing my record count in the output file.

Ex:this is the record in input file.

```
..more records..
1|XXXX|3|NNNNNNN
2|XXXX|3|MMMMMMM
3|XXXX|3|AAAAAAA
4|XXXX|3|BBBBBBB
5|XXXX|3|NNNDDDD
6|YYYY|3|QQQQQQQ
7|YYYY|3|4444444
8|YYYY|3|1111111
..more records..
```

The output file that hadoop is creating is as below:

```
file 0 :
..more records..
1|XXXX|3|NNNNNNN
2|XXXX|3|MMMMMMM
3|XXXX|3|AAAAAAA

file 1:
4|XXXX|3|BBBBBBB
6|YYYY|3|QQQQQQQ
7|YYYY|3|4444444
8|YYYY|3|1111111
..more records..
```

*line 4 for ID: XXXX should not be there!
Why hadoop is not filtering the counter correctly?

Comment: can you provide the code which is doing this?

Comment: I have the GUI task developed in Syncsort DMExpress tool.
While running this task on edge node I am getting correct result, but running this task on Mapreduce is giving me more records.

Comment: Since we can't see your code, which you've already been asked for and ignored the request, we could provide nothing but random suggestions. My current suggestion is that your code is broken at line eight.

Comment: Is syncsort internally creating an MR job to process the filter/sort rules you have provided?

Comment: @BillWoodger: Line 8 you mean for ID YYYY, but the file is breaking at line 3 and as 3 line are written for id XXXX, the first line in file 1 should be the first record of id YYYY!

Comment: @mbaxi : I am putting the task in a job and then running that job on hadoop.

Comment: Statistics show that line 8 *is the most common line-number ever to have contained an error*. Since you've not shown your code (still) I can only guess, so have guessed the most likely. Can't do more than that with the information.

Comment: @BillWoodger - I think 'JustStarted' hasn't written any MR job, (s)he has simply created a synsort job/task and running it on hadoop cluster.

Comment: @JustStarted are you using DMX-h?

Comment: @mbaxi that may be so, but where I come from SyncSORT uses code. You don't just think hard and it happens by magic. May not be the same here, of course.

Comment: @BillWoodger: I have not written any code for this. Like mbaxi said, I have created the job in syncsort job/task and I am running it on hadoop cluster.

Comment: @mbaxi: Yes I am using DMX-h!

Comment: Even if you don't want to call it code, can you show what it is you have done?

Comment: @mbaxi you seem to know a bit about this. Can you think of a new tag, or find and existing one, for this? mfx-hadoop perhaps? The SyncSORT tag is really for their SORT product (which formally is called Mainframe Express/MFX), primarily on an IBM Mainframe but also could be used (maybe) where the SORT product itself is on another platform.

Comment: @BillWoodger we can tag it as "sycsort dmx-h" or "dmx-h", i would prefer first one."syncsort-etl" is also an option.

Comment: @JustStarted, I agree with Bill, can you share the job/task xml, possibly some configuration/order is not correct.

Comment: @mbaxi Pronlem with the dual tags, SyncSORT is both a company and a product, and the tag is for the product, originally developed over 40 years ago. How about `syncsort-dmx-h`? Then the syncsort tag is just for the sorting product, as previously.

Comment: @BillWoodger makes sense to me.